# Puppet Exec wont run on refresh only

Tags: puppet

I have a test program

```
$oracle_gi_home = '/opt/gi/19.14'
$listener_name = 'LISTENER'

concat { '/tmp/test/tmp.file':
  ensure => present,
}

concat::fragment { 'Add tmp file':
  target  => '/tmp/test/tmp.file',
  content => 'This is a new test 2',
  notify => Exec['Restart listener'],
}

exec { 'Restart listener':
  command     => "${oracle_gi_home}/bin/srvctl status ${listener_name}",
  user        => 'oracle',
  group       => 'oinstall',
  cwd         => $oracle_base,
  environment => ["ORACLE_HOME=${oracle_gi_home}"],
  timeout     => 0,
  logoutput   => true,
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

I get this weird message in debug saying Exec wont be executed because of failed refreshonly? The file was updated??

```
Notice: /Stage\[main\]/Main/Concat\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]/File\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]/content: content changed '{md5}f4378e6270895e6f3549c314c70c47e3' to '{md5}b46e769a18b468bdf1b60166ed4d5548'
Debug: /Stage\[main\]/Main/Concat\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]/File\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]: The container Concat\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: /Stage\[main\]/Main/Concat\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]/File\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]: The container /tmp/test/tmp.file will propagate my refresh event
Debug: /tmp/test/tmp.file: The container Concat\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Concat\[/tmp/test/tmp.file\]: The container Class\[Main\] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: /Stage\[main\]/Main/Exec\[Restart listener\]: '/opt/gi/19.14/bin/srvctl status LISTENER' won't be executed because of failed check 'refreshonly'
Debug: Class\[Main\]: The container Stage\[main\] will propagate my refresh event
```

I tried subscribe, notify

Comment: `refreshonly => true` on an `Exec` resource requests that its command be run only in the event that the resource is refreshed.  I read the message you ask about as saying that the Exec *was not* refreshed, so the command will not be run.  Do you have reason to think that there's something wrong with that?

Comment: In this program the concat::fragment does run and updates the file. Then in the log it shows it calls the exec with the notify but then it says it “won’t be executed because of a failed refresh only”. What would cause it to fail?

Comment: Also if I remove the /temp/test/temp.file it still does not run

Comment: The natural place for the `notify` would be on the `Concat` resource, not on any of the associated `Concat::Fragment`s.  Aside from that usually being more semantically correct, there are good, though somewhat technical, reasons why a fragment might not publish an event even when the overall file is in fact updated.

Comment: Thanks John that did the trick. When adding Notify to Concat it behaved as it should

Answer (score 0):

A `Concat` resource represents an overall file.  It is generally with this resource, not with any of the contributing `Concat::Fragment`s, that one should establish relationships.  That's usually the right thing to do semantically, as it is rare to have a relationship with only one section of a larger file.  It also turns out to be more reliable  from a technical standpoint, because of implementation details of the Concat module.

In this particular case, that would mean putting the `notify` on `Concat[/tmp/test/tmp.file]`.  It's not necessarily wrong to also have one on the fragment, but it would be redundant.  Result:

```
concat { '/tmp/test/tmp.file':
  ensure => present,
  notify => Exec['Restart listener'],
}

concat::fragment { 'Add tmp file':
  target  => '/tmp/test/tmp.file',
  content => 'This is a new test 2',
}

exec { 'Restart listener':
  command     => "${oracle_gi_home}/bin/srvctl status ${listener_name}",
  user        => 'oracle',
  group       => 'oinstall',
  cwd         => $oracle_base,
  environment => ["ORACLE_HOME=${oracle_gi_home}"],
  timeout     => 0,
  logoutput   => true,
  refreshonly => true,
}
```